# React custom hooks not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to implement a very simple custom hook called useOpen that simply returns a boolean (isOpen). I want to show or hide some text in App.js based on isOpen state. Currently, nothing is being rendered and trying to console.log(isOpen) in App.js gives me undefined. Thanks in advance!

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import useOpen from './CustomHooks/useOpen'

function App () {
 const {isOpen} = useOpen;

return (
<div className='App'>
  {isOpen && <p>isOpen</p>}
</div>
)
}

export default App
```

useOpen.js

```
import { useState } from 'react'
export default function useOpen() {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true)
    return { isOpen }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re missing the parens on `useOpen`. Should be `useOpen()`.

```js
const {isOpen} = useOpen; // missing ()
```

```js
const {isOpen} = useOpen();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call function useOpen at the component.

Answer (score 0):

you need to execute the hook to get its value
and you don't need to put it in a object to deconstruct it on the other side

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import useOpen from './CustomHooks/useOpen'

function App () {
 //const {isOpen} = useOpen;
 const isOpen = useOpen();

return (
<div className='App'>
  {isOpen && <p>isOpen</p>}
</div>
)
}

export default App
```

useOpen.js

```
import { useState } from 'react'
export default function useOpen() {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true)
    //return { isOpen }
    return isOpen
 }
```